# stop displaying default message after displaying custom component UI to create record

Tags: lightning, lightning-design-system

I have a default message as loading which has to be displayed until its been navigated to custom UI page of component.
I havd tried using 
var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
dismissActionPanel.fire();

But this will completely close the modal.
Now default message is showing in the UI screen itself.

PFA
[image: UI of component]

Any help will be highly useful.

Thanks and Regards,
Nag

Adding javascript

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) { 
        var opportunityRecordVal;                                    
        var action = component.get("c.getRecord");        
        action.setParams({ recordId : component.get("v.recordId") });       
        action.setCallback(this, function(response1) {
        var state = response1.getState();
        component.set("v.oppr",response1.getReturnValue());   
            if(state === "SUCCESS"){                    
                opportunityRecordVal = response1.getReturnValue(); 
                var action1 = component.get("c.createnewcvr");                
                action1.setParams({ accId : opportunityRecordVal.Account__c });
                action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                var state1 = response.getState();
                    if (state1 === "SUCCESS"){
                        if(response.getReturnValue() === 'Success KYC'){
                            var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                            dismissActionPanel.fire();
                            var createRecordCVR = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
                            createRecordCVR.setParams({
                                "entityApiName": "Client_Validation_Request__c" ,
                                "defaultFieldValues":{
                                    "Contact__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Contact__c,
                                    "Account__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__c,
                                    "Contact_Email_Address__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Contact__r.Email,
                                    "Tel_Number__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Contact__r.Phone,    
                                    "GST_ID__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__r.GST_ID__c,
                                    "PAN_Number__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__r.PAN__c,
                                    "Account_Registration_Number__c" : opportunityRecordVal.Account__r.RegistrationNumber__c
                                  //"RecordTypeId" : Schema.SObjectType.Client_Validation_Request__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Default').getRecordTypeId()
                                }
                            }); 
                            createRecordCVR.fire();
                        }
                        else if(response.getReturnValue() === 'Success Quote'){
                            var action45 = component.get("c.getAccAddress");
                            action45.setParams({accId : opportunityRecordVal.Account__c })                             
                            action45.setCallback(this,function(response45){
                            var jsStr = action45.getReturnValue();
                            component.set("v.billingAddress",jsStr[0].acc);
                            component.set("v.postingAddress",jsStr[0].acc1);
                            var state45 = response45.getState(); 

                                if(state45 == "SUCCESS"){
                                    component.set("v.isModalOpen",true);
                                    var action1 = component.get("c.CreateNewQuote");
                                    action1.setParams({ recordId : component.get("v.recordId") });
                                    action1.setCallback(this, function(response) {
                                        var quote = response.getReturnValue();
                                        component.set("v.quot",response.getReturnValue());
                                    });                                
                                    $A.enqueueAction(action1);
                                }
                            });                                
                            $A.enqueueAction(action45);
                    }
                    else{
                            component.set("v.message","Error: "+response.getReturnValue());
                        }
                    }              
                });
                $A.enqueueAction(action1);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }

    })
```

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" controller="KYCQuote">
    <!--Style-->
    <aura:html tag="style">
          .slds-modal__container{
        height : auto;
        width: 70%;
        max-width: 70rem;
        }
        .modal-body{
        height : 500px !important;
        max-height: 1000px !important;
        }       
        .customFooter{
        display: inline !important;
        }
    </aura:html> 

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="quot" type="apttus_proposal_proposal__c"/>    
    <aura:attribute name="error" type="Boolean"/>

    <aura:attribute name="oppr" type="Opportunity__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="accountRecord" type="object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="acv" type="String[]"/>

    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String" default="Loading..."/>


    <div class="slds-scrollable slds-p-around_medium slds-text-heading_small" id="modal-content-id-1">
       <p style="height: 108px; word-wrap: break-word;">{!v.message}</p><br/>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
       <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.accept}" label="Accept" />
    </div>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <div class="modal-header slds-modal__header slds-size_1-of-1">
        <h4 class="title slds-text-heading--medium" >KYC</h4><!-- Quote/ -->
    </div>

   <!-- <force:recordData aura:id="recordLoader" recordId="{!v.recordId}" fields="Opportunity__r.Account__c" targetFields="{!v.accountRecord}"/> -->   
    <ui:scrollerWrapper class="sWrapTest"> 

  <!--  <aura:iteration items="{!v.accountRecord}" var="ar"> 
        <div>
            {!ar}
        </div>
    </aura:iteration>
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
        <lightning:textarea name="input2" label="V-aaa" value="{!v.accountRecord}"/>  --><!--{!v.oppr.Account__r.Billing_Country3__c}-->
   <!-- </div> -->
    <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Billing &amp; Posting Address</div>
                </div>  
    </lightning:layout>
        <div><b>Please choose billing and posting address</b></div>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.acv}" var="vb"> 
        <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox"/> {!vb}           
        </div><br/>
    </aura:iteration>

        <lightning:textarea name="input2" label="V-aaa" value="{!v.accountRecord}"/>
        <lightning:textarea name="input2" label="V-aaa" value="{!v.acv}"/>

    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_x-small" ><!--style="max-height:400px; overflow:auto;"  -->
        <lightning:recordEditForm objectApiName="apttus_proposal_proposal__c" >
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Proposal Information</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>


            <!--Section 1-->
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">           
                  <lightning:messages />        
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account__c" value="{!v.quot.Account__c}"/><!--value="{!v.quot.Account__c}{!v.accId}" -->
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="PriceList__c"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Opportunity__c" value="{!v.recordId}"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Primary_Contact__c" value="{!v.quot.Primary_Contact__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="APTS_Quote_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Selling_Country__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Order_Type__c" value="{!v.oppr.OpportunityType__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Old_Owner__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Channel__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_code_Backup__c" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Xcode__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="X_Code_Account_Backup__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Quote_Total1__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Discount_Exception__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 2-->       
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                   <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Send Back</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages />        
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="SentBack__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="SentBackReasonText__c"/> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Sent_Back_Reason__c"/> 
                  </div>
            </div>  

            <!--Section 3-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Pricing Information</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages />
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Base_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Account_Entity_Use_Code__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Gross_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Total_Discount_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Tax_Percentage__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Total_Discount__c"/>
                  </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Tax_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div></div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Net_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 4-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Billing &amp; Posting Address</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages/>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="BillContact__c" value="{!v.quot.BillContact__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="PostingContact__c" value="{!v.quot.PostingContact__c}"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Special_Terms__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 5-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Approval Information</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages />
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Level_of_Approval_Done__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager1__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Level_of_Approval__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager2__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Approval_Status__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager3__c"/>
                  </div>
                    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager4__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Manager5__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>

            <!--Section 6-->
            <lightning:layout>
                <div class="demo-only" style="padding:0.5rem;background:#FFFAF1">
                    <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-text-title_bold">Additional Information</div>
                </div>  
            </lightning:layout>
            <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap" >            
                  <lightning:messages />
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Payment_count__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Payment_Net_Total__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="TDS_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Validated__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Payment_Amount__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Sales_Channel_1__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="CreditRequest__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Re_Process_By_With_DateTime__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Sent_Back_DateTime__c"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName=""/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Re_Process_DateTime__c"/>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.save}" label="Save" />
                <lightning:button class="slds-button_brand" onclick="{!c.cancel}" label="Cancel" />
            </div>

        </lightning:recordEditForm>  
    </div>
    </ui:scrollerWrapper>

    <aura:html tag="style">
            .cuf-content {
                padding: 0 0rem !important;
            }
            .slds-p-around--medium {
                padding: 0rem !important;
            }       
            .slds-modal__content{
                overflow-y:hidden !important;
                height:unset !important;
                max-height:unset !important;
            }

    </aura:html>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? is this LWC or Aura component? I think we need to see the javascript related to this modal in order to understand why the Loading... message stills shows up in the modal.

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo have added the javascript for your reference

Comment: can you also post the aura component please?

Comment: @CarlosNaranjo added component code

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to use a better structure to avoid issues like the one you are dealing with. I think that because you are using multiple enqueActions you can take a look to [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises#whats-all-the-fuss-about) to help you control them on a better way.

Take a look to [this SFDC article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm) to make sure you don't have other issues.

Do a search and see what better suits your structure. If after adopting this pattern you still have problems we could look some other solution.

There is something related that perhaps can also help [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/161568/7429).

You can also use helper functions to clear a bit the operations and simplify your logic.